# pygame headless no font

Tags: python, pygame, python-imaging-library

When I'm in pygame headless mode with

```
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

the surface has no rendered fonts, only black filled rectangles. (I only tried it on a linux pc.)

when I turn off headless mode everything works perfectly.

Code:

```
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
.....drawing on the surface.....
...
data = pygame.image.tostring(self.screen, 'RGB')
img = Image.fromstring('RGB', (128,64), data).convert()
img.show()
img.save('./img/out.png')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add what O.S. you are using (windows/linux/os x) - anyway, I think you way out will be reporting this as a bug against pygame itself.

Comment: I have sent a but report on this issue. In the meantime I tried a workaround by using a bitmap font, which works quite well.